# ngRoute tabs menu after login in AngularJS 1.7.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have ngRoute that route the users in login page and if success login user can land in dasboard page.

The problem is that in dashboard page i need of two or more tabs that render a (view) html page drived from reletive controller.
 One inportant point in angularjs scenarios, as i was follow in some example, are that i need to use  in index page for render tabs content.
But i want and need to render view by tabs in dashboard page: because index is used for login mechanism.

I have spent many time to achieve this, following example and tutorial and it seems to be the most difficult part of the whole my project. 
What i need is a child route inside dashbord page.  I would possibly avoid moving from ngRoute to Ui-router. 
I search for a simple solution.

code:

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'components/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
})
.when('/logout', {
    resolve: {
        deadResolve: function($location, user) {
            user.clearData();
            $location.path('/');
        }
    }

})
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'components/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'

})
.when('/dashboard', {
    resolve: {
        check: function($location, user) {
            if(!user.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        },
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
    // it is possible a child route for two tabs??
})

.otherwise({
    template: '4045'
});


$locationProvider.html5Mode({
 enabled: true,
 requireBase: true
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});


    Controller

    app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $location, user, $http,  $window) {

    $scope.tabs = [
                    {
                        title: "Visualized",
                                templateUrl: 'components/trax.html',
                                controller:'testCtrl'
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Pure JSON",
                        templateUrl: 'components/trax2.html'
                    }
                        ,
                    {
                        title: "Other",
                        templateUrl: 'json.html'
                    }
                ]
     //...
});



what i try:


  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{ tab.title }}" active="tab.active">
         <div ng-include="tab.templateUrl"></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

So ng-include render well html page, but without controller function.

Can you put me in right direction for achieve this apparently easy tab in landing page ofter login successful?

Thank you!

Comment: you can try to use directives with `transclude` (which is your 5th parameter in `link` function)

Comment: thanks i try and replay

Answer (score 0):

So easy solution for big problem by  directive. Awesome
hope help.
thank you

```
  <uib-tabset>
      <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" select="onTabSelected(tab.slug)">
        <div ng-include="tab.templateUrl"></div>  </uib-tab>
      </uib-tabset>
      <div ng-controller="testCtrl">

      {{nome}}

        <div>
```